# UML State Machines: Deep History Pseudostate and Final State

Tags: uml, state-machine

In UML state machines, what exactly happens to the history of a composite state if a final state of a substate is entered?

Consider the state machine shown below. After the trigger sequence T1-T2-T3-T4 it will end up in the final state. By entering the final state the history of the region of State21 gets cleared, and since the region also gets completed by this, the completion transition to State1 will be executed. Now, when trigger T5 gets enabled, the state machine enters the deep history state. I suppose that in this situation the deep history state represents State21, which means the state machine enters State21 and then executes the transition from the initial pseudostate of State21 to State211. Is this correct?

I prefer the behavior described above, but I can see an alternative in which the history of State2 also gets cleared when the final state in State21 is entered. In that case the state machine executes the transition from the the initial pseudostate of State2 to to State22. So what do you think?

[image: State Machine]

Comment: You first explanation is correct for your diagram. To be cleared, State2 needed to have FinalState within it and a completion transition from State21 to this FinalState, and a completion transition from State2 to State1. In this case the second explanation would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of deepHistory description

> This type of Pseudostate is a kind of variable that represents the **most recent active state configuration** of its owning Region. As explained above, a Transition terminating on this Pseudostate implies restoring the Region to that same state configuration, but with all the semantics of **entering a State** (see the Subclause describing State entry).

Your first behavior description seems to be the good one. By trigerring T1, T2, T3, T4, and T5 transitionns you are back to State21 entry i.e. State211.

Answer (score 1):

I read this diagram in the following way:

While in State1 you can enter into State2 by calling T1 (which is a fresh sequence) or via T2 (a retry of the previous sequence).

When the application / system is in State1 it appears to have logic in it that allows for retrying a previous State2 sequence in certain situations. As such deep history keeps those process variables around in the parent state until State1 can make a decision on which way it wants to proceed.

However ambiguities exist in the example state machine model:

1. The transition back to State1 is not named/numbered, and
2. An intermediate partially complete state, that requires deep history, has not been defined. The model needs an exit state / criteria defined as a sub-state within State21 that serves as the source for this unnamed transition back to State1.

The current flow within State21 only has one end state and therefore runs to completion every time. Its only when you need to re-enter a state at a given sub-state location that deep history makes sense.